# How paste many columns side by side from Excel to notepad++

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, copy-paste

Assume that I have three columns in Excel

```
MGM_COMPTEUR
CIA_CD_CRV_CIA
CIA_DA_EM_CRV
CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE
CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ
CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ
```

The second column is :

```
AS
AS
AS
AS
AS
AS
```

the 3rd one is :

```
MGM_COMPTEUR
CIA_CD_CRV_CIA
CIA_DA_EM_CRV
CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE
CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ
CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ
```

Now I need as final result :

```
MGM_COMPTEUR   AS MGM_COMPTEUR   
CIA_CD_CRV_CIA AS CIA_CD_CRV_CIA 
CIA_DA_EM_CRV  AS CIA_DA_EM_CRV  
CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE AS CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE 
CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ AS CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ 
CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ AS CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ
```

I tried using CTRL + paste after making espace between columns.
But it does not work

Comment: just select all three in excel, press copy and paste it in notepad++, or did I misunderstood your issue?

Comment: If you are pasting 1 column at a time use notepad++ column mode. See https://riptutorial.com/notepadplusplus/example/17820/column-editing

Comment: What result are you getting, and how *(exactly)* is it different from what you want?

Comment: @Zina, no I want to paste each column seperated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want one space between every column (not fully clear from the output, which sometimes shows more than one space).

In your Excel sheet, create e.g. right of the 3 columns an extra column that concatenates all strings with a space in between:

```
=CONCATENATE(A7, " ", B7," ", C7)
```

Copy this formula for all rows

The result will be

```
MGM_COMPTEUR AS MGM_COMPTEUR
CIA_CD_CRV_CIA AS CIA_CD_CRV_CIA
CIA_DA_EM_CRV AS CIA_DA_EM_CRV
CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE AS CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE
CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ AS CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ
CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ AS CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ
```

These cells you can copy and paste to Notepad(++).

Comment: Why? Just copy and paste the three columns would work.

Comment: @teylyn Than I get tabs in between. Although the output of the question is unclear since now I look better there are sometimes multiple spaces, I assume he wants just one space.